# Drop down menu does not work on username

Tags: php, html, css

I have made a login system and I am trying to add a dropdown to the username for settings. However, I can make it look like it has a dropdown but no menus appear.

```
<?php else:?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A09hopper.xyz</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])):?>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?><span class="caret"></span></a></li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1-2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>

    <?php else:?>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>
</ul>


  </div>
</nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have tried everything I can think of but to no avail.

Comment: Is whole menu does not show up or just some parts? Which links are not showed?

Comment: yes, the username is displaying. I just can not add a drop down menu to it.

Comment: @AliİnsanSoyaslanthe whole menu doesn't show up. It looks like you have pressed it but nothing shows up

Comment: Can you see menu codes on page source, if you can see probably it's about javascript or css issue, If you cant see menu codes on source it should be about php. But likely its about javascript.

Comment: @AliİnsanSoyaslan I can see the HTML clearly in the page source :/

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed my issue. The code below is the fix.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A09hopper.xyz</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])):?>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
        <?php else:?>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>
</ul>


  </div>
</nav>
```